# how to get the relationship from Collection of relationships between two nodes using springdata Neo4j with GraphRepository

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have two entities like Users and Accounts. User node related to Account node 
with any of the 20 relationships. Please find the sample image design attached

[image: nodelayout image]

i need to search accounts for  corresponding users using any of the 20 relationships.  i used the cypher query for retriving user details and the accounts.. Relationship between the two entity will be either any one of the 20 relationships . so i can't annotate the @RelationshipEntity type value.  Please find the code for example 
User.java

```
public class User
{ 
    private Long id;    
    String fulltextsearch;   

    String user_id; 

    String status; 

     @Relationship(type = "perm")
     List<Acronym> acronym;
     .....
         ...    
}
```

Acronym.java

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
@RelationshipEntity
public class Acronym {
@GraphId
    Long id;
    String acronym;
    @StartNode
    private User user;
    @EndNode
    private Account account;
....
....
}
```

Userrepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "User", path = "User")
public interface Userrepository extends GraphRepository<User> { 
    User findByLogin(@Param("login") String login);

    @Query("MATCH p=(user:User)-[r*0..1]->(account) WHERE user.login =~('(?i).*'+{Login}+'.*') RETURN p")
    Collection<User> findByloginContaining(@Param("login") String login);
}
```

i tried creating objects for each relationship (ie 20 relationship object.). i'm not sure if that correct way to get the value.
Could anyone please help me to know to fetch the  relationships against the account? it always retrives as null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OGM/SDN 4 does not support unknown relationship types. The type of relationship *must* be specified on a @RelationshipEntity.

One way of doing this is as you said, create a @RelationshipEntity per type, but this also means that you must specify 20 such relationships in your User class, because the relationship type differs (even though the start/end nodes are the same). This may not be ideal, and difficult to manage.

If your application primarily works with dynamic relationship types, the OGM may not be a good fit.

NOTE: Mapping custom query results to entities is only supported in OGM 2.x / SDN 4.1. You cannot return a path, just the entities that make up the path such as nodes and rels.

Comment: thank you for your valuable response. I will updated my projects to support for OGM 2.x / SDN 4.1. As I'm still in learning curve, can you please suggest any link with sample code to start with.

Comment: The reference manual is a good place to start- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/. Then there's a sample project at https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/tree/4.1 and a blog post (2 part series) at http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/02/24/upgrading-spring-data-neo4j-4-1.html